# Why won't ifstream open this file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define BRIGHTNESS_FILE "/sys/class/backlight/radeon_b10/brightness"

int main()
{
     ifstream brightness_file("BRIGHTNESS_FILE");
     int a;
     brightness_file >> a;
     cout << a;
}
```

I've checked the path and permissions for the file.
I am at a loss on why it won't read from it.

EDIT

I fixed the whole define thing with BRIGHTNESS_FILE, but it still won't open. I've checked the path multiple times just to be safe.

Comment: Is it `/sys/class/backlight/radeon_b10/brightness` absolute path of the file?

Comment: Are you trying to open `"BRIGHTNESS_FILE"` or `"/sys/class/backlight/radeon_b10/brightness"`?

Comment: Please don't edit the post with the solution. The answers are for that. Rolling back again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define `BRIGHTNESS_FILE` as constant string literal:

```
#define BRIGHTNESS_FILE "/sys/class/backlight/radeon_b10/brightness"
```

But don't use it at all:

```
ifstream brightness_file("BRIGHTNESS_FILE");
```

`"BRIGHTNESS_FILE"` is **also** a string literal - it has nothing to do with your macro. That's why its content won't be replaced by preprocessor.

What you need is:

```
ifstream brightness_file(BRIGHTNESS_FILE);
```

Now, `BRIGHTNESS_FILE` will be changed to "/sys/class/backlight/radeon_b10/brightness" and your file should properly opened (if it exists and is accessible, of course).

Answer (score 5):

I assume you don't have a file named `"BRIGHTNESS_FILE"`. Because that's the file name you are trying to open. Remove the quotation marks in order to use your macro-defined string.

```
ifstream brightness_file(BRIGHTNESS_FILE);
```